# Is there theoretical description of such plasmonic nanostructure?

Tags: electromagnetism, resource-recommendations, plasmon

I'm preparing a research about plasmonic nanoparticles and I'm interested about their arrays placed above a metallic film (like on the picture).

[image]

Until now i found following articles:

pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/nl0515100

http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00340-006-2203-4

http://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.83.165107

However I'd appreciate an article which describes SPHERICAL nanoparticles arranged in ARRAYS, close to metal film.

And do anyone know about application of such structures in SERS? I found descriptions and experimental realisations of similar structures, but still far from depicted on the picture above.